# Add context menu to .exe files

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, context-menu

I've added a few custom context menus in the past, very successfully. However, I am trying to add an option to disable dpi scaling from the context menu, as many applications require me to go to settings and do this manually. However, under `HKCR\.exe` there was no shell option. So I created one and added a key, with a command and extended (to make it available by shift clicking.

Here is the output from reg query `HKCR\.exe\shell\DPI Compatibility\command`:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.exe\shell\DPI Compatibility\command
(Default)    REG_SZ    reg.exe Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v %1 /d "~ HIGHDPIAWARE"
```

The command works on its own, and successfully added DPI settings. However, even with shift-clicking, there's no option. I've tried restarting.

I think the problem might be with the PersistentHandler key that exists under the .exe key. I suspect it's taking precedence over the old `Shell/ShellEx system`. `HKCR\.exe\PersistentHandler` contains data `{098f2470-bae0-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}`, which is a key that contains data `Null Persistent handler` and key `PersistentAddinsRegistered`, which contains more data pointing to keys.

I'm running Windows 10 if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. This always happens.

The default value for HKCR.exe is "EXEFile", which is a class that contains shell and shellex. By putting my command in there, everything works swimmingly.